# Quartz job No record found for selection of Trigger with key

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, quartz

## Quartz problem

When I start my spring boot application, Error handling misfires problem will occurre with high probability.
The following is the log

```
[2022-06-28 17:17:59.538] [ERROR] [QuartzScheduler_ProtectionQuartzScheduler-tw-node12191656407859503_MisfireHandler] [o.s.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore] >>> [protection-web] msg=MisfireHandler: Error handling misfires: Couldn't retrieve trigger: No record found for selection of Trigger with key: 'com.test.protection.web.rest.service.quartz.job.LoadMetaQuartzJob.a002cf4a8a3a418fa62b8c1d6d071992[once]' and statement: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'ProtectionQuartzScheduler' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?
org.quartz.JobPersistenceException: Couldn't retrieve trigger: No record found for selection of Trigger with key: 'com.test.protection.web.rest.service.quartz.job.LoadMetaQuartzJob.a002cf4a8a3a418fa62b8c1d6d071992[once]' and statement: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'ProtectionQuartzScheduler' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1538)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.recoverMisfiredJobs(JobStoreSupport.java:984)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.doRecoverMisfires(JobStoreSupport.java:3264)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.manage(JobStoreSupport.java:4012)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport$MisfireHandler.run(JobStoreSupport.java:4033)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No record found for selection of Trigger with key: 'com.test.protection.web.rest.service.quartz.job.LoadMetaQuartzJob.a002cf4a8a3a418fa62b8c1d6d071992[once]' and statement: SELECT * FROM QRTZ_SIMPLE_TRIGGERS WHERE SCHED_NAME = 'ProtectionQuartzScheduler' AND TRIGGER_NAME = ? AND TRIGGER_GROUP = ?
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.SimpleTriggerPersistenceDelegate.loadExtendedTriggerProperties(SimpleTriggerPersistenceDelegate.java:110)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate.selectTrigger(StdJDBCDelegate.java:1819)
    at org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreSupport.retrieveTrigger(JobStoreSupport.java:1536)
    ... 4 common frames omitted
```

The following is my simple java code and config of quartz:

```
// DLockAcquired is my distributed lock
  @Async
  @EventListener(ApplicationReadyEvent.class)
  @DLockAcquired(keyName = "datasource-init")
  public void init() {
    logger.info("Initialize Synchronize datasource on startup ...");
        try {
      this.doSyncDatasource();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error("Initialize datasource failed, error: ", e);
    }

    aferInitialize.set(true);
  }
```

After some if else statement, it will create a job as following code:

```
  public void scheduleJobOnce(JobDetail jobDetail, TriggerKey triggerKey)
      throws SchedulerException {
    Scheduler scheduler = schedulerFactoryBean.getScheduler();
    Trigger simpleTrigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger().startAt(new Date()).withIdentity(triggerKey)
        .withSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.simpleSchedule().withRepeatCount(0)).build();
    try {
      scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, simpleTrigger);
    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
      logger.error("Quartz schedule job failed, {}.",
          JsonUtil.parseObjectToString(jobDetail.getJobDataMap()), e);
      throw e;
    }

  }
```

My quartz config

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = ProtectionQuartzScheduler

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false


org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000


org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.acquireTriggersWithinLock = true
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true


org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = qzDS
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.driver = com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.provider = hikaricp
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.URL = jdbc:mysql://localhost:15307/quartz_db?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8&useSSL=false&allowMultiQueries=true&failOverReadOnly=false&connectTimeout=10000&retriesAllDown=3&secondsBeforeRetryMaster=0&queriesBeforeRetryMaster=0
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.password = 123456
org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.maxConnections = 10
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: We also getting this Exception since some time. I'm also interested in a solution / workaround.
Currently we prune all quartz tables via `delete from qrtz_*` to fix this issue :/